# Does SAX in Python have an index that tells me where I am in an XML file? And how would I find that out?

Tags: python, xml, debugging, sax

I have a specific and a general question.

Suppose I'm using SAX to deal with the below XML, but it's actually 17MB and far more complex. There are no errors with the code, but because it's so complex and I probably shouldn't have gone near SAX in the first place, I'm getting a frustrating logic error - it's sometimes outputting a value that I'm not interested in, sometimes rightly ignoring it. This logic error is the only thing stopping me from finishing the project. I'm trying to debug the code, but that's very frustrating because even my truncated test XML file has 42,000 lines.

So my specific question is how can I see which line of the XML file is triggering any given startElement. Does startElement or ContentHandler have an index or something that tells you where in the file it's up to?

My general question is how can I find out how to do this for myself? I can flail around on Google, and Stack Overflow is a tremendous resource that I'm very grateful for, but if I could independently investigate the attributes of the things I'm working with, that would be much more satisfying. For instance, is there a way, in my code, I can get a list of all the things that hang off startElement or a variable or anything, really. Len() tells me how long something is, Type() tells me what type it is. Are there other useful meta commands that I can fall back on when I'm not sure what *kind* of problem I'm having?

I kind of anticipate being shouted at for asking two questions in one, but I can see how to ask the general question without being shouted at for being too nebulous.

Credit to http://pyxml.sourceforge.net/topics/howto/node12.html for this code.

```
<collection>
  <comic title="Sandman" number='62'>
    <writer>Neil Gaiman</writer>
    <penciller pages='1-9,18-24'>Glyn Dillon</penciller>
    <penciller pages="10-17">Charles Vess</penciller>
  </comic>
</collection>
```

I deal with the XML with the below code:

```
from xml.sax import saxutils

class FindIssue(saxutils.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self, title, number):
        self.search_title, self.search_number = title, number

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        # If it's not a comic element, ignore it
        if name != 'comic': return

        # Look for the title and number attributes (see text)
        title = attrs.get('title', None)
        number = attrs.get('number', None)
        if (title == self.search_title and number == self.search_number):
            print (title, '#' + str(number), 'found')
            
from xml.sax import make_parser
from xml.sax.handler import feature_namespaces

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create a parser
    parser = make_parser()

    # Tell the parser we are not interested in XML namespaces
    parser.setFeature(feature_namespaces, 0)

    # Create the handler
    dh = FindIssue('Sandman', '62')

    # Tell the parser to use our handler
    parser.setContentHandler(dh)

    # Parse the input
    parser.parse("test.xml")
```

Comment: You're probably looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.setDocumentLocator ...

Comment: Sax is a bit low level to handle XML, other libraries can save you some sweat by building you an XML tree for free.

Comment: "I have a specific and a general question". Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your example that also prints the row and column of the matching element.

```
import io
from xml.sax import saxutils
from xml.sax import make_parser
from xml.sax.handler import feature_namespaces


class FindIssue(saxutils.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self, title, number):
        self.locator = None
        self.search_title = title
        self.search_number = number

    def setDocumentLocator(self, loc):
        self.locator = loc

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name != "comic":
            return
        title = attrs.get("title")
        number = attrs.get("number")
        if title == self.search_title and number == self.search_number:
            if self.locator:
                print("Line", self.locator.getLineNumber(), "column", self.locator.getColumnNumber())
            print(title, "#" + str(number), "found")


# Create a parser
parser = make_parser()
parser.setFeature(feature_namespaces, 0)

issue_finder = FindIssue("Sandman", "62")
parser.setContentHandler(issue_finder)
parser.parse(
    io.StringIO(
        """
<collection>
<comic title="Sandman" number='62'>
<writer>Neil Gaiman</writer>
<penciller pages='1-9,18-24'>Glyn Dillon</penciller>
<penciller pages="10-17">Charles Vess</penciller>
</comic>
</collection>
""".strip()
    )
)
```